# How i embed add to cart button in woo commerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes, wordpress-ecommerce

1) I want to embed the woo commerce add to cart button on a non shop page.
2) I also want to change its text and replace with an image.
3) Last thing is i want to embed a variety product above this button and use the button for this.

Comment: i already searched but find nothing. i don't need exact coding, i need a direction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create link with `href="your_site.com/?add-to-cart={product_id}"` - this works for simple products. If you`re using variable product - see HTML from single product page. If you have variable procut - woocommerce create a form instead a add to cart button. See parameters and create similar form where you need and submiting this form will add variable product to cart.

Comment: where i can find the script for the variable product in woocommerce  code???

Comment: Hey, i found small tutorial [here](https://nicola.blog/2015/09/18/creating-custom-add-to-cart-url/). Might help you.

Comment: i checked it, it's nice but i want that i also show the drop down in variation, it solves the problem by adding a static url. And i want a dynamic system, where i can also select from the dropdown

Comment: Than you should know how works post_types, taxonomies, woocommerce. You should be exprienced developer. I think you will not find ready solutions or code. Looks into woocommerce template files. Also in `single-product/add-to-cart/` folder. This will best code example for you.

Comment: thanks for your precious time